# Abstract method issue

Tags: php-5.3

```
<?php
abstract class a{
    abstract protected function test();
    function threeDots(){
        return '...';

    }
}
class b extends a{

     protected function test(){
        echo $this->threeDots();
    }
}
$obj = new a();


   $obj->test();
?>
```

Above code giving error...But dont able to understand Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error on this line:

`$obj = new a();`

Because you can't create instances of abstract classes.
Perhaps, you wanted to write: `$obj = new b();` ?